# How to get right camera preview independent from the screen orientation?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, screen-orientation

Why in the `portrait` screen orientation the camera surface is rotated by -90 degrees "90 degrees anticlockwise". I want the camera preview to be normal regardless of the screen orientation. How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

`mCam.setDisplayOrientation(90);` use it inside `surfaceChanged(...)`

> ***setDisplayOrientation***
>   Set the clockwise rotation of preview display in degrees. This affects the preview frames and the picture displayed after snapshot. This method is useful for portrait mode applications. Note that preview display of front-facing cameras is flipped horizontally before the rotation, that is, the image is reflected along the central vertical axis of the camera sensor. So the users can see themselves as looking into a mirror.

This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos. This method is not allowed to be called during preview.